# Bootstrap multi-select: Adding images instead of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

firstly here's the link: http://liveweave.com/We9Qg8

I want to add images to a dropdown with multi-select, I am using bootstrap [multi-select plugin](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect), I've figured out how to add text to the dropdown after the main text of each dropdown. I can't seem to find how to add images after the checkboxes.

HTML code:

```
<div class="example">
            <select id="example-multiple-selected" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
                <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
                <option value="option-4">Option 4</option>
                <option value="option-5">Option 5</option>
                <option value="option-6">Option 6</option>
            </select>
        </div><!--/.example -->
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example-multiple-selected').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
                allSelectedText: 'No option left ...',
                selectAllText: 'All Libraries',
                buttonText: function(options, select) {
                    return 'Libraries';
                },
                buttonTitle: function(options, select) {
                    var labels = [];
                    options.each(function () {
                        labels.push($(this).text());
                    });
                    return labels.join(' - ');
                },
                optionLabel: function(element) {
                return $(element).html() + '(' + $(element).val() + ')';
            }
            });
        });
```

Any help on how to add images would be appreciated.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror3 is not defined`. Please debug your code in your browser's console.

Comment: can you please tell me where did you find this error? in the link I've posted?

Comment: Press F12 when you're in that website.

Comment: These are the errors generated by liveweave because I did not add my sources in the way in wants, I've added directly in HTML tab. I don't have any issues on my local systems + I did not post that there is some issue with my code, I was trying to add and enhancement.

Comment: Usually with these plugins when you update a select tag, you should refresh it, did you try `.multiselect('refresh')`?

Comment: It seems like you can use jQuery `.append()` so you can basically append any HTML you like.

Comment: I've tried append(), it won't work with the plugin because the plugin changes the html structure.

Comment: Well, I fail to see in your code where exactly you're trying to add images. In addition, if the plugin provides the functionality you're looking for then you should use it, any problems you have after trying to use it will be easy fix.

Comment: Well, there is a way to add images but I'm not sure how, someone who is a bit experienced can easily do it.

Comment: There are a number of jQuery functions to do that, however, if the plugin already provides that functionality I highly recommend using the plugin's function. In any case, the jQuery functions are `.append()`, `.insertBefore()`, `.insertAfter()`, `.add()`, `.html()` etc.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to tell me but they don't work, you can try it yourself, they don't work on this plugin.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to help when you're not providing any code or link to your original project.

Comment: Thank you for you effort, the reason I've created a online demo is anybody can edit it and add the images. There is no difference between the original and online demo. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Well, I've tried many ways to make this work, it seems like this plugin renders what ever you tell it as text, it refuses to accept html :/ I think that with this plugin: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ - you can achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you. You are right it won't accept any HTML, whatever needs is there needs to be done in the plugin configuration.

Comment: That's the thing, I went over all of the plugins methods and it doesn't seem like that possible. I'm pretty sure bootstrap-select will give you that functionality.

Comment: thank you for trying mate. I can't change the plugin because it's already embedded into the application I'm working on. I'm sure there is a method because I did it before, with the option optionLabel and function has to be passed which adds couple of variables, the first variable would be constant like the main url of the images, the second variable would be the image name which would be passed in each <option>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to this after a bit of research:

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/ohk5mgne/)

The JS code to be used is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.multiselect').multiselect({
        buttonWidth: 'auto',
        numberDisplayed:15,
        enableHTML: true,
        optionLabel: function(element) {
            return '<img src="http://placehold.it/'+$(element).attr('data-img')+'"> '+$(element).text();
        },
        onChange: function(element, checked) {
            //console.log(element.attr('value') + checked);
            $("ul.multiselect-container").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
                //console.log(element.attr('value'));
                var valueAttr = $(this).attr('value');
                if (element.attr('value') == valueAttr) {
                    var checkParent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().hasClass('active');
                    //console.log(checkParent);
                    if (checkParent == false) {
                        $(this).removeAttr('disabled')
                    }else{
                        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled')
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```